# Move list item from one unordered list to another

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to move my list item from one unordered list to another. update.js.erb is called when the update happens ( I can see it being called in the log with no errors).

I'm very new to jQuery so I appologize for my ignorance.

```
<% if @task.complete? %>
  $('#task_<%= @task.id%> li').detach().appendTo($('#complete_tasks ul'));
  $.('#complete_tasks').sortable_list();
<% else %>
  $('#task_<%= @task.id %> li').detach().appendTo($('#incomplete_tasks ul'));
  $.('#incomplete_tasks').sortable_list();
<% end %>
```

I saw .detach() in [How to move an item from one list to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956373/how-to-move-an-item-from-one-list-to-another)

I have tried many different forms but my guess is I'm selecting the list or list item wrong.

Any / all feedback is greatly appreciated ! :)

Update 1:

```
ul id="complete_tasks" data-update-url="http://localhost:3000/tasks/sort_incomplete" class="ui-sortable"
  li class="task" id="task_1"
  ...
```

And similarly the incomplete_tasks

```
ul id="incomplete_tasks" data-update-url="http://localhost:3000/tasks/sort_complete" class="ui-sortable"
  li class="task" id="task_7"
  ...
```

Update 2: Here is what ended up working, I had a different function call after this when I originally tested it that created the issue.

```
<% if @task.complete? %>
  $('#complete_tasks').append($('#task_<%= @task.id %>'));
<% else %>
  $('#incomplete_tasks').append($('#task_<%= @task.id %>'));
<% end %>
```

Without the extra $( ... ) the function would just print #task_2 so I added that and deleted the bad function call and everything worked great!

Comment: You don't need to detach.  If you use appendTo (or append) then it moves the element.  It doesn't create a copy.  Also, get rid of the `$()` in the `appendTo` - you only need #ID

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice! I didn't realize the $() usage was wrong! It also seems that chrome says the id (or maybe this is some other form of identification) of the element is: li#task_1.task even though every id of the form task_# is unique do I need to refer to the element, id, and class to properly select it?

Comment: You only really need the ID to select the element.  There's no need for the element type and class.

Comment: Thanks archer! 
Ended up working I had an incorrect function call afterwords that wasn't causing an error but was stopping the append for some reason...
Thanks! If you add it as an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: Glad to help - answer added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to detach. If you use `appendTo` (or append) then it moves the element. It doesn't create a copy. Also, get rid of the `$()` in the `appendTo` - you only need #ID.  And you only need the ID to select an element - no need for the tag name and class.

Answer (score 1):

This should be sufficient

```
$('#task_<%= @task.id%> li').appendTo('#complete_tasks ul');
```

But this will move all the **list items** under `#task_` to the ul inside `complete_tasks`

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! For some reason it doesn't work. I figured I should flesh out my question with the HTML of the involved lists and list items.